# Does windows ensure that memory will contain only one copy the same dll as in linux?

Tags: windows, dll, shared-libraries

I always thought .dll is working the same way as .so in linux,

but some article says not.

Does windows ensure that memory will contain only one copy the same dll as in linux?

I don't have a clue to check it myself in windows,so I can only ask here.

**UPDATE**

Anyone knows how do verify this manually?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ,seems windows dll shares only on disk,not memory,how can I verify that ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Windows_DLLs

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library

Comment: @Waleed ,what's your conclusion ?

Comment: The dll code block is shared among processes, but each process has his own copy of the data block used by the DLL, so yes, it will ensure that the memory will contain only one copy of the same dll

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short description: [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell#Shared_in-memory_modules), basically in modern Windows it use a technique called Memory Mapping where the DLL is loaded once, **if** both processes try to load the DLL from the same directory. So to answer your question, it is working the same was as in Linux.

Comment: seems windows support this by fixed address of dll,not suporting PIC,so the effect is limited,maybe only for their own dll,right?

Comment: That is something of the past, the fixed address in DLLs don't do much in a modern Windows (Win2000 and later).

Comment: @Haukman,do you have a way to verify this manually(how are you so confident in this otherwise)?

Comment: It's hard to actually prove this, you would have to run a low-level debugger and see what physical memory a page is mapped to. But it's a "known" technique that Microsoft did after DLL Hell in earlier Windows (like version 3). Here's some info: http://www.flounder.com/hooks.htm

Comment: I don't trust things that can't be proved easily.

Comment: That I can't help you with. The bottom line is that's the way Windows works. It's an old perception that Linux did this amazing thing (and others) that Windows can't do, but to be honest, Windows has improved a lot over the last 10 years and now has a lot of the techniques that was introduced with Linux. We have to give some credit to the rich man :)

Comment: It's not really too hard to prove this. Start up thousands of wordpad processes and note that the system doesn't start thrashing.

Comment: Hehe, well, data is still allocated per process, so it would be hard with that test (1000s of Wordpads) to prove that the code isn't duplicated.

Comment: @Haukman But you can work out how much memory is data and how much is code.

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL can be loaded at the same base virtual address in two processes then there will only be one copy of the DLL in physical memory.

Since Windows does not use position independent code, if a DLL cannot load at its preferred base address it will be rebased and thus not be able to share physical memory with other instances.

Comment: So it's random whether there're more than one copies in memory?

Comment: No. Not random. You choose a base address that doesn't clash with other DLLs.

Comment: @David Heffernan,no you can never guarantee that ,can you?

Comment: if you know what dlls your process will load then you can easily avoid a clash. I think I've answered your question now.

Comment: @David Heffernan,the purpose of PIC is that I can work for arbitrary process,and when the process is arbitrary,you can never know what dlls it will load.

Comment: I'm fully aware of what PIC is for. The saving grace of the Windows approach is that when you encounter DLLs that need rebasing they tend to be only loaded by a small number of processes, often just one.

Comment: There's no point in using shared library only for one process.It's already wrong in design.

Comment: That wasn't really what I meant. In practice, at least in my experience, rebasing seldom happens. In any case, I already answered the question.

Comment: In modern the base of a DLL isn't used to determine if it's shared or not. That was something that 16-bit Windows was struggling with, and part of what caused DLL Hell.

Comment: @Haukman Your information is incorrect. I'm talking about sharing in physical memory of the code segment.

Comment: I don't think we need to argue back and forth, but in a 32-bit+ windows, the physical address is completely unrelated to the DllBase. Everything goes through memory mapping.

Comment: Like always,lack of prove is the reason of argument.

Comment: @haukman base address determines whether a dll can be loaded without rebasing. If it can be loaded without rebasing then the physical memory can be shared.

Comment: @compile-fan Why do you ask the question if you don't listen to the answer? Clearly you have a very low opinion of Windows and have already decided what you want to believe in. Apparently you can't use web search to read about this copiously documented topic. Even if you could you would disbelieve what was written if it didn't match your pre determined beliefs. Faith based learning is not effective. I answered your question concisely and accurately. Why can you not acknowledge that?

Comment: To further add to this discussion, Windows Vista and later (can) use ASLR which will always rebase DLLs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization So IMHO the base of DLLs are less important nowadays, and following that logic I doubt Windows uses that to determine if it can share the code segment. But I agree with you @David-Heffernan that @compile-fan seem less interested in the answer.